# laravel bind multiple parameters in routeserviceprovider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm struggling getting the below code working. I am able to get to level 1, but bind level 2/3/4 is something i can't get working.

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/profile/{level1}/{level2?}/{level3?}/{level4?}', 'TestController@tester');
```

In my RouteServiceProvider i have this binding:

```
$router->bind('level1', function($test){
    return \App\urlSlugs::where('slug', $test)->get();         
});
```

In my controller i have this function

```
public function tester($stuff){
    return $stuff;
}
```

Now, i don't understand how to add the level2/3/4 to the binding. They are optional, it should bind so i can use them in the function.

All levels are needed to retrieve the correct object (i have to extend the actual binding later). They don't relate to other objects (it's 1 single object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slashes can be part of the parameter to simplify things

```
Route::get('/profile/{levels}', 'TestController@tester')
    ->where('levels', '.+');

$router->bind('levels', function($test){
    dd(explode('/', $test));
});
```

If all 4 levels need to be present, you can try this untested regex:

```
Route::get('/profile/{levels}', 'TestController@tester')
    ->where('levels', '([^/]+\/){3}[^/]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a little bit tricky. But you can use progressive binding. Check something like below:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    //
    $router->bind('level1', function($test) use ($router){
        $router->bind('level2', function($test1) use ($test,$router){
          $router->bind('level3', function($test2) use ($test,$test1,$router){
            echo $test.' '.$test1.' '.$test2;
          });             
        });
    });
    parent::boot($router);
}
```

The whole idea, this breaks, if one of the levels does not exist, so you can take that into consideration while building your levels.